# How to use a variable for a line of code of an script?

Tags: shell-script, variable

I don't know how to use variables for further executing in a script.

I tried the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM = 0
echo Number $NUM > text.txt
```

but I get the following error:

`num.sh: 3: num.sh: NUM: not found`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There must not be any whitespace around `=` in variable declaration in shell.

Remove the whitespaces:

```
NUM=0
```

Also if you don't have any good reason, don't use all uppercases for a user defined shell variable name as there is chance that this could conflict with any environment variable.

Better do:

```
number=0
```

Comment: +1 for lower case variables. I've heard seasoned programmers - people much smarter than I am - saying that bash variables should always be upper case...

Answer (score 3):

Don't use spaces in line `NUM=0`

Answer (score 2):

You may need to remove the space after `NUM` , so the script should look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=0
echo $NUM > text.txt
```